# Python import module from directory

Tags: python, python-import

Hello I have a dir structure like

```
~/program
```

Inside I have subdirs like
    /cdm, /google, /folder1, /folder2

I have created in every dir and subdirs the **init**.py file.
Inside one of those folder i run a python script like

```
python script.py
```

And I get the following error

```
from google.protobuf.message import DecodeErrorImportError: No module named protobuf.message
```

The google directory has /gooogle/protobuf/message folder with files in it..

I tried with the PYTHONPATH adding it but no luck...

Whats wrong with it??

This is the script code

```
import time
import binascii

from google.protobuf.message import DecodeError    
from google.protobuf import text_format
```

Comment: could you add the output of `tree` command run inside `~/program`. include at least the part that is relevant here.

Comment: kindly also add the content of `script.py`